# sharepoint custom EditForm.aspx not reading the correct item ID?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I made a custom EditForm.aspx but when I click on an item in the list to edit, it gets the data for the very first item in the list, every time. The title gets the right information, but the custom list form doesn't. I checked the parameters and there is a ListItemId that has QueryString(ID) as the location, so that is correct. Anyone know why the custom list form isn't showing the right record?

Really appretiate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you created the custom page, but following this guide always works for me:

http://www.cjvandyk.com/blog/Articles/How%20do%20I%20-%20Customize%20the%20NewForm.aspx%20or%20EditForm.aspx%20of%20my%20SharePoint%20list.aspx

Comment: thanks for the replay, i used a custom list form with the edit option.

Answer (score 0):

i do a work around to solve this issue by recreating the form and then pasing the fields. and then i found this resource that explain what i discover is the third option list in the post.

http://www.sharepointblog.com/2010/01/adding-columns-to-custom-list-form-in.html#comment-form

Answer (score 0):

I built custom Edit forms, in SP Designer. All you need to do is (in SP Designer) link the form to the list by Item ID. Not sure you can miss that as is part of the Next-Next process. Try to re-create it and see if it works.